# Change the Ribbon of a RTE field in the Send Mail action for Webforms for Marketeers

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I want to change to Ribbon of the RTE Field which is shown in the send mail action on a webforms form. I found an item in the core database `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Mail`, but this profile doesn't seem to be used for the send mail action. I also found (using fiddler) that the following xml control is used: `Sendmail.Editor` but don't know if this has something to do with the ribbon.
Basicly I want to be able to offer our customer more functionality in the RTE field of the send mail action and don't know how this is done.

using:

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers Library")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.1.0.3458")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("2.1.0 rev. 100920")]
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to have a Send Mail button on the RTE ribbon? How do you want this to work? Would it open a custom window with a form?

Comment: No Mark, I want to edit the buttons that are visible on the tab of the Send mail Action. If you edit content which is used in the send mail action there also is a Rich Text Editor, but it's kind of limited.

Comment: Ahhh I see, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the RTE profile that is used for any RTE field by specifying the path of the profile in the source field of the template.